# Sending a notification to a class method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a class method that crunches through a lengthy operation (10-15 second load time).

```
+(NSString*)shrinkKML
{
   //lengthy operation
}
```

What is the best way to send a notification to interrupt it when applicationDidEnterBackground gets thrown from the app delegate?  I would usually implement a NSNotificationCenter call to my custom class that sets a flag and then my "lengthy operation" could just check the flag periodically.  Catch here is that class methods (correct me if I'm wrong) can't depend on instance variables.  Is there another way?

Comment: Is this a cancelable operation? I mean it a synchronous class method, correct? Does it even check to see if it's canceled at any point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Catch here is that class methods (correct me if I'm wrong) can't depend on instance variables.

You could make the flag a global variable.

Class .m file:

```
BOOL isCancelled;

@implementation SomeClass

+ (void)shrinkKML {
    isCancelled = NO;

    // Do stuff and check isCancelled
}

@end
```

App Delegate .m file:

```
extern BOOL isCancelled;

@implementation AppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    isCancelled = YES;
}

@end
```

---

However, if I may make a suggestion, a good way to create and manage long running asynchronous tasks is using NSOperation and NSOperationQueue. They have this cancel functionality built in. You would create an NSOperationQueue object where this task is started, and then add the shrinkKML as an NSOperation to the queue. To convert the shrinkKML function into an NSOperation, you could subclass NSOperation. It may take a bit of work to implement, but its better than re-inventing the wheel.

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for that answer - confirmed a bunch of stuff for me.  I actually have this running asynchronously but didn't realize that the cancel functionality is built in!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest periodically checking for the state directly using `[UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationState`.

Comment: I've never used applicationState before - could you provide a code example of how to detect the background state?